# I'm Getting a CS1705 Error When I go to Compile my Code and I Don't Know How I should Fix This

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I am currently attempting to make Windows Form using C# GUI Front End for a database. When I go to compile my code I get the CS1705 Error and specifically this:

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1705 Assembly 'MySql.Data' with identity 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Database_GUI C:\Users\goodt\OneDrive\Desktop\Database_Project\Database_GUI\CSC 1 Active"

Where would I even start in trying to fix this?

So far I haven't really tried any solutions because I don't understand why this error is occuring in the first place. I've looked up the error code but I'm still confused as to what exactly went wrong.

Comment: You're trying to use a .Net 7 mysql package within a non .Net 7 application. _'MySql.Data' with identity 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' uses ``'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0``, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity ``'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0``_ You either need to reference an older mysql package or update your app to use .net 7

Comment: How would I update my app to .net 7?